# Format string on Linux and Solaris

Tags: solaris, ksh

I have a Korn Shell script, and one part of it is that it takes a given date in YYYYMMDD format and outputs it in YYYY/MM/DD format. At first I tried

```
typeset displaystart=`date --date="${gbegdate}" '+%Y/%m/%d'`
```

which works fine on Linux, but Solaris's `date` doesn't have a `--date` option. I then tried

```
typeset displaystart=`echo ${gbegdate:0:4}`/`echo ${gbegdate:4:2}`/`echo ${gbegdate:6:2}`
```

which also works on Linux, but on Solaris it just outputs `//`.

How can I format this date string in a way that works on Linux and Solaris?

Comment: Why do you have the `bash` tag if it's Korn Shell, not Bash?

Comment: That was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Korn shell` doesn't have `${variable:start:length}` syntax; this is a `bash` extension to POSIX shell syntax.

You can use `echo "$variable" | cut -cstart-end` instead.

```
typeset displaystart=`echo $gbegdate | cut -c1-4`/`echo $gbegdate | cut -c5-6`/`echo $gbegdate | cut -c7-8`
```

Or maybe you could change your script to use `bash` instead of `ksh`.

Comment: Your first sentence is slightly incorrect, `ksh` has been implementing this extension since 1993. It is even plausible `ksh` was the first to implement it, or at least, there might have been some communication between Alan Cox and David Korn, given the same syntax was picked by both shells the same year they introduced it. The real issue is that `/bin/ksh` is `ksh88` on Solaris.

Comment: @jlliagre When I googled "ksh parameter expansion" I didn't see it shown in any of the pages I found. I guess they're all behind the times as well.

Comment: The advanced bash scripting guide from the Linux documentation project states that the "Variable expansion / Substring replacement" feature has been borrowed from ksh. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 2):

The `${variable:start:length}` extension to POSIX shell syntax was introduced in the version of `ksh` released in 1993, precisely named `ksh93`, and was also introduced in `bash 1.13` the very same year.

The [Advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) from [the Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/) states:

> **Variable expansion / Substring replacement**
>
> These constructs have been adopted from ksh.
>
> **${var:pos}**
>
> Variable var expanded, starting from offset pos.
>
> **${var:pos:len}**
>
> Expansion to a max of len characters of variable var,
>   from offset pos. See Example A-13 for an example of the creative use
>   of this operator.

The issue is that on Solaris 10 and older, `/bin/ksh` is providing a previous `ksh` standard, `ksh88`, which didn't implemented this feature.

On the other hand, on Linux, `ksh` is often `ksh93` which supports substring extraction. That explains why your script works under Linux `ksh` (if you really tested it on `ksh`.)

An old derivative of `ksh93` is available on Solaris 10 though. It is named `dtksh` ans is located in `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh`. Your command should work unchanged with it however I wouldn't recommend to fully switch to `dtksh`, this shell being phased out from Solaris but you might still use it from a regular `ksh` script to workaround your issue:

```
typeset displaystart=$(/usr/dt/bin/dtksh -c "gbedate=$gbedate; echo \${gbegdate:0:4}/\${gbegdate:4:2}/\${gbegdate:6:2}")
```

Note that Solaris 11 and newer provide both GNU `date` and `ksh93` so you wouldn't have that issue in the first place.